# .png icon not loading in a JFrame window

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, embedded-resource, imageicon

[image: a simple png image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Program {
public static JButton button;
public static void main(String args[]){
    JFrame win=new JFrame("title");
    win.setVisible(true);
    win.setSize(500,500);
    win.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    ImageIcon i=new ImageIcon("icon.png");
    button=new JButton("hello",i);
    win.add(button);
    button.setToolTipText("click me");

}
}
```

When I run the file , I just get the text "hello" on the button but no image.
(This image was downloaded from http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iynque/flat-ios7-style-documents/512/png-icon.png)

The image is stored in the project src file.

Comment: Where is the image stored in relationship to the source/project

Comment: I agree, png images are supported, so icon.png must be in the wrong location.

Comment: Your icon has to be in the classpath, or relative path from the classpath.

If you build it to a jar file, where does the icon sit inside the jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this: 
   ImageIcon i=new ImageIcon("src/icon.png");

Comment: This will almost certainly fail at time of deployment.  Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Answer (score 3):

Image shouldn't be in `src` but in main application directory, usually level above. So move your icon or change code to:

`ImageIcon i=new ImageIcon("src/icon.png");`

You should consider adding it to your resources (so it will be placed in jar) and opening via `getResource()`. Next problem in example is that it won't be displayed until window is refreshed by resize or other action. Add this line at the end:

`win.pack();`

Or other method that will refresh window content.

Answer (score 0):

```
getClass().getResource("icon.png")
```

will do it, if your image file is under the same dir of the Program.java, and when compiled, it indeed is packed into the same dir where the `Program.class` is.